# Finding Index of All Patterns Within Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, arrays

I'm using a Pandas dataframe indexed by datetimes that looks something like this:

```
TimeSys_Index
2014-08-29 00:00:18    0
2014-08-29 00:00:19    0
2014-08-29 00:00:20    1
2014-08-29 00:00:21    1
2014-08-29 00:00:22    0
2014-08-29 00:00:23    0
2014-08-29 00:00:24    0
2014-08-29 00:00:25    0
2014-08-29 00:00:26    0
2014-08-29 00:00:27    1
2014-08-29 00:00:28    1
2014-08-29 00:00:29    1
2014-08-29 00:00:30    1
2014-08-29 00:00:31    0
2014-08-29 00:00:32    0
2014-08-29 00:00:33    0
...
```

I want to find the index (time) for every occurrence of the pattern [0, 0, 1, 1]. Using the above sequence I'd like it to return ['2014-08-29 00:00:18', '2014-08-29 00:00:25']. The kicker is this needs to be vectorized or at least very quick.

I was thinking of running a correlation of the full vector with the pattern vector and finding the indices where the resulting vector equals 4, but there's got to be a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the shifted values:

```
>>> df.head()
                     val
TimeSys_Index           
2014-08-29 00:00:18    0
2014-08-29 00:00:19    0
2014-08-29 00:00:20    1
2014-08-29 00:00:21    1
2014-08-29 00:00:22    0
>>> i = (df['val'] == 0) & (df['val'].shift(-1) == 0)
>>> i &= (df['val'].shift(-2) == 1) & (df['val'].shift(-3) == 1)
>>> df.index[i]
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-08-29 00:00:18, 2014-08-29 00:00:25]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution for a non-datetime indexed dataset. When I run this as you've posted I get  " 'RangeIndex' object is not callable." - Any suggestions?  Thank you!