# Pandas find sequence or pattern in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

Here's some example data for the problem I'm working on:

```
index     Quarter    Sales_Growth
0          2001q1    0
1          2002q2    0
2          2002q3    1
3          2002q4    0
4          2003q1    0
5          2004q2    0
6          2004q3    1
7          2004q4    1
```

The `Sales_Growth` column tells me if there was indeed sales growth in the quarter or not. 0 = no growth, 1 = growth.

First, I'm trying to return the first `Quarter` when there were two consecutive quarters of no sales growth.

With the data above this answer would be `2001q1`.

Then, I want to return the 2nd quarter of consecutive sales growth that occurs AFTER the initial two quarters of no growth.

The answer to this question would be `2004q4`.

I've searched but the closest answer I can find I can't get to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539166/3225420

I am a Pandas beginner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing subsequence matching.  This is a bit strange, but bear with me:

```
growth = df.Sales_Growth.astype(str).str.cat()
```

That gives you:

```
'00100011'
```

Then:

```
growth.index('0011')
```

Gives you 4 (obviously you'd add a constant 3 to get the index of the last row matched by the pattern).

I feel this approach starts off a bit ugly, but the end result is really usable--you can search for any fixed pattern with no additional coding.

Comment: Picked this answer for two main reasons:  First, it worked and secondly I understand it.  Other answers may have worked just as well but were beyond my understanding.  The fault is not on the people who provided them that I don't understand, it's on me.  I need to learn more. Simply sharing my reasoning.

Comment: @SDS: Cheers.  I also found this way of dealing with it much easier to think about.  Plus it's less typing.  :)

Comment: Just...superb! :)

Answer (score 9):

For Q1:

```
temp = df.Sales_Growth + df.Sales_Growth.shift(-1)
df[temp == 0].head(1)
```

For Q2:

```
df[(df.Sales_Growth == 1) & (df.Sales_Growth.shift(1) == 1) & (df.Sales_Growth.shift(2) == 0) & (df.Sales_Growth.shift(3) == 0)].head(1)
```

Comment: This should be the top answer. @john-zwink's answer above doesn't generalize to multiple columns, requires you to serialize/delimit the data manually, and would generate the entire string in memory before searching. Shifting in the correct solution!

Answer (score 3):

Building on the earlier answers. Q1:

```
temp = df.Sales_Growth.rolling_apply(window=2, min_periods=2, \
    kwargs={pattern: [0,0]}, func=lambda x, pattern: x == pattern)
print(df[temp==1].head())
```

In the rolling_apply call, `window` and `min_periods` must match the length of the pattern list being passed to the rolling_apply function.

Q2: Same approach, different pattern:

```
temp = df.Sales_Growth.rolling_apply(window=4, min_periods=4, \
    kwargs={pattern: [0,0,1,1]}, func=lambda x, pattern: x == pattern)
print(df[temp==1].head())
```

Comment: You're effectively making a Python loop here, which is slow.  Usually in Pandas we avoid that.