# How to get a subset of rows from a group in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a column ID and a binary column, like the example below

```
     ID    BINARY_MASK
0   101        1
1   101        0
2   101        1
3   101        1
4   101        1
5   101        1
6   101        0
7   101        1
8   102        1 
9   102        1
11  102        1
12  102        1
13  102        0 
14  102        0
```

What I want to do is get the *first four consecutive entries that are 1, per ID group*. 
The result I would like to see is the following:

```
     ID    BINARY_MASK
2   101        1
3   101        1
4   101        1
5   101        1
8   102        1 
9   102        1
11  102        1
12  102        1
```

The index inside the group where there are four consecutive ones differs per group, like in the example.
How do I do this?

I have tried the solution that was offered [by Bill G in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555031/pandas-find-sequence-or-pattern-in-column), but that didn't work for me.

Working with Pandas dataframes and Python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create helper Series for [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values compared by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) and chain with another condition, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['BINARY_MASK'].ne(df['BINARY_MASK'].shift()).cumsum()
m1 = df.groupby(s)['BINARY_MASK'].transform('size') >= 4
m2 = df['BINARY_MASK'] == 1

df = df[m1 & m2]
print (df)
     ID  BINARY_MASK
2   101            1
3   101            1
4   101            1
5   101            1
7   101            1
8   102            1
9   102            1
11  102            1
12  102            1
```

Answer (score 3):

#### [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [`groupby` with `head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html)

Easiest thing to do is to filter which are ones prior to grouping.  You can do the filtering in several ways, I chose to use `query`.

```
df.query('BINARY_MASK == 1').groupby('ID').head(4)

     ID  BINARY_MASK
0   101            1
2   101            1
3   101            1
4   101            1
8   102            1
9   102            1
11  102            1
12  102            1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I have worded my question wrong (edited now) and am looking for the first 4 _consecutive_ ones in the data. If you look at the example, for ID 101 I want to retrieve indices 2, 3, 4 and 5, and with your answer I would get 0, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: That completely changes the nature of the question. I suggest rolling the edit back and asking a new question.

Comment: Ok, then I will do that.

Comment: @jezrael I'd still advise that OP ask a new question.  We should discourage changing the nature of the questions after people have answered.

Comment: Tell me about it.  I should have.  I thought it was a simple change and it turned into something that confused me.  I should've said something up front.

Comment: No worries.  I'm only speaking of what we should aspire to do.  I'm imperfect and mess this up all the time.  I wish OP would ask that question because what you posted is exactly what they need.

Comment: Yes!  It is.  @ChubaChuubs your original question did mention consecutive ones.  jezrael's answer addresses that.  You should select his answer.

Comment: @ChubaChuubs - I absolutely agree if your question should be modify radically, but here is add one word also mentioned in last paragraph, so new question is not necessary (in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` + `head` :

```
df[df['BINARY_MASK']==1].groupby('ID').head(4)

     ID  BINARY_MASK
0   101            1
2   101            1
3   101            1
4   101            1
8   102            1
9   102            1
11  102            1
12  102            1
```